# Eclipse CDT C++ error

Tags: c++, eclipse

I use window Eclipse CDT gdb to debug a C++ program. When I wrote may own makefile as follows

```
all: prog1

prog1: prog1.cpp
       g++ -o prog1 prog1.cpp
```

It compiled and run successfully. But if I click the debug button, it says `no available source main....`.

***Edit***

If I copy the same program to a new C++ project in Eclipse with its internal `makefile` (instead of writing my own makefile), I can use debug mode. But eventually, I have the following errors.

`No source available for "__mingw_CRTStartup` How should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your line

```
g++ -o porg1 prog1.cpp
```

to

```
g++ -o prog1 prog1.cpp
```

Probably the name of the output (i.e., the program) is wrong, and therefore Eclipse can't launch it.

Comment: @ Greg. Sorry for my typo. The name in eclipse is right. I have updated the program name.